# Compile time errors while working with C++/CLI examples

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to read a string which is a 'Number' from a file, and convert it back to an integer. Following is my code, which is C++/CLI

```
int InformationReader::getThreshold()
{
    StreamReader ^reader = gcnew StreamReader("threshold.dat");
    System::String ^thresholdStr = reader->ReadLine();

    Int32 thresholdNum;

    boolean a = Int32::TryParse(thresholdStr,thresholdNum);

    return 0;

}
```

But, as soon as this code get executed, I get the following error

```
1>InformationReader.cpp(29): error C2065: 'Int32' : undeclared identifier
1>InformationReader.cpp(29): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'thresholdNum'
1>InformationReader.cpp(29): error C2065: 'thresholdNum' : undeclared identifier
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C2065: 'boolean' : undeclared identifier
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C2653: 'Int32' : is not a class or namespace name
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C2065: 'thresholdNum' : undeclared identifier
1>InformationReader.cpp(31): error C3861: 'TryParse': identifier not found
```

OK now this is alien to me, because I went through number of questions and answers, and in all of them they have followed the similar approach as I have used but I am getting an error. Why is this?

Comment: I am not C++ expert, so want to know how do you specify out parameter in C++ like in C#  example `Int32.TryParse("2", out i);`. Just curious cause the whole purpose of TryParse is not throwing an exception.

Comment: You fell into the trap of compiling snippets without their harness.

Comment: The common `using namespace System;` directive is missing.  Boolean should be capitalized or be bool.

Comment: @HansPassant: the 'bool' stuff, that is cool. I corrected it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the first compilation error you see:  You need a `System::` in front of the `Int32 thresholdNum;`

Comment: Alternately, you could simply use `int` in the place of `Int32`, in both places (yes, `int::TryParse` should work too).

Comment: @Medinoc: Yes, I did it now. Thanks a lot for the help